# "The feed from New On Our Blog seems to be broken, due to an error 'Invalid document end' on line 128."

Tags: 7, feeds

I run a Drupal 7 website and I have a separate WordPress blog. The blog generates a feed I display (RSS2 version) in a block on the Drupal website via the Aggregator module. The last feed shown on the Drupal website is from November 24, 2017. The newer 2 posts have not made it onto my Drupal website. However, when I check the feed itself, the posts are present in the feed.

The error message that Drupal shows is:

> The feed from New On Our Blog seems to be broken, due to an error
> "Invalid document end" on line 128.

I checked the feed; there is no mention of line 128 on feed validator. Another error shows up for line 187:

> line 187, column 0: url must be a full URL:  [redacted]/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/adding_texture.mp4

I don't understand why I am getting these error messages. The lines look okay to me.

- I installed updates
- I deleted my browser's cache (Firefox ESR)
- I deleted the Drupal cache
- I added a new test post to the blog, and confirmed it shows on the feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a simple smiley `:)` wrought all the havoc. The smiley was situated in the first paragraph of a post and was therefore transferred via the feed to Aggregator.

Removing the smiley removed the errors and now the feed is showing correctly again.

I don't know what exactly is wrong with ':)', but somehow it messed things up. Explanations are welcome.